# Accessible directories when using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP to power my website here: http://driz.co.uk/ and have the standard setup of having an App folder and a Cake folder in the server root. I also have some other directories for other projects which SHOULD be accessible also but because of my Cake website it is preventing me from accessing them in the browser. e.g. http://driz.co.uk/taschen/ is a folder with an index.html file inside which would work but Cake instead causes a 404 error.

How do I get around this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to place files into app/webroot/ directory
That way I managed to install Wordpress blog.
Not CakePHP-Dao way probably but it works.

Answer (score 0):

[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) maps the `taschen` folder to some other URL. The configuration for mod_rewrite can usually be found in the file `.htaccess`.

Comment: In CakePHP if the .htaccess file is not found then it reverts to the index.php that does similar functionality so it's more than one place to causes the problem. Not sure why though as other systems like WordPress don't have problems like this and they rewrite based on the directory structure... Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are your project directories within cake's webroot dir? Normally there is no issue accessing files that exist.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact server, the questions might need to be rephrased, but do you have root access to your server? Can you add a new site to sites-enabled, edit a current site, or edit httpd.conf?

If so, then you could point the document root to the web folder, and then use site aliases for the other folders.